# In how many ways can spouses be arranged around a circle?

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can five married couples be seated around a circle so that spouses sit together?

I tried 5! = 120 but I am not sure if  my answer meets all conditions set in the question.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: Please use a yet more descriptive title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permitting the five couples around the circle we have $\frac{5!}{5}=4!$ to account for the rotations of a permutation being the same. (I.e. 12345 is the same permutation as 23451 when placed in a circle. )

Then you can permute individuals within each couple. There are 2! Arrangements for each couple.

Thus the total arrangements is $4!*(2!)^5$

Answer (score 0):

First let men's  are arranged around  circle in $4!$ ways now for every wife to seat with there husbands there are $2$ was either on right or left side therefore wife's can seated in $2^5$ ways.
$$ $$
Hence total number of ways are $ 4!.2^5 $

Comment: The question doesn't make any assumptions about the couples being heterosexual.

Comment: Dispite all ways you consider couple answer remain same . One can consider men's and women's as 1st and 2nd me.ber of couple.

Comment: You can't if the couples consist of two men, or two women, or people who don't identify with a binary gender.

Comment: In my opinion, I think one should go with what society considers normal.